# Как перейти на другой state без отправки сообщения пользователя?

Tags: python, telegram, aiogram

```
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor, types
from aiogram.contrib.fsm_storage.memory import MemoryStorage
from states import Form

bot = Bot(token='')
storage = MemoryStorage()
dp = Dispatcher(bot, storage=storage)


@dp.message_handler(commands=['start'])
async def start(message: types.Message):
    await message.answer("Здравствуйте")
    await Form.number.set()

@dp.message_handler(state=Form.number)
async def start(message: types.Message):
    await message.answer("Введите номер телефона")
    print(1)
    await Form.size.set()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
```

Как перейти на state Number без сообщения пользователя?
Я проверил и обнаружил что переход на другой state осуществляется только с сообщением пользователя. Как это избежать?

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы сразу переходить к state после запуска по команде `start` перенесите вопрос из него в команду после приветствия. Должно получиться как то так:

```
@dp.message_handler(commands=['start'])
async def start(message: types.Message):
    await message.answer("Здравствуйте\nВведите номер телефона")
    await Form.number.set()


@dp.message_handler(state=Form.number)
async def phone(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        data['phone'] = message.text
    await message.answer("Введите размер")
    await Form.size.set()


@dp.message_handler(state=Form.size)
async def size(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        data['size'] = message.text
    await message.answer(f"Вы указали номер: {data['phone']} и выбрали размер: {data['size']}")
    await state.finish()
```

таким образом вы будете сразу запрашивать у пользователя данные. Ведь логично, что переход в state без триггера, коим и является ответ пользователя, не происходит.

Comment: Прям вообще никак без триггера? Жаль...

Comment: @Zemmeus объясните, какой сценарий вы хотите получить, вполне возможно его можно реализовать